# "Не" или "ни" – как правильно?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Скажите, пожалуйста, "не" или "ни" нужно писать в следующем предложении?

Этот человек, как бы вы о нём не (ни) судили, принял правильное решение.

Comment: не(ни)судили,принял /// Что с пробелами?

Comment: Дайте точный ответ,если можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужна частица ***ни***.

*Этот человек, как бы вы о нём **ни** судили, принял правильное решение.*

[**Неударяемые частицы *не* и *ни***](https://therules.ru/vowels-13/)

> Частица **ни** употребляется перед сказуемым в придаточных предложениях для усиления утвердительного смысла, например:
>
> *Не мог он ямба от хорея, как мы **ни** бились, отличить* (Пушкин).

**Примеры** из Национального корпуса русского языка:

***Как бы ни судили** о нем потомки, они не в силах изменить уже произошедшего.* [А. Алексеев. Возвращение к фактам, или как восстановить единство истории // «Наука и жизнь», 2006]

***Как бы ни судили** об этом человеке его недоброжелатели, которых у него тьма, но он принадлежит к людям необыкновенным.* [А. В. Никитенко. Дневник (1834)]